# align center a checkbox in a View (RN)

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

My code is:

```
      <View style={{...styles.tableRow, backgroundColor: index % 2 == 1 ? "#F0FBFC" : "white"}}>
        <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
          <Checkbox label="" color="success" checkboxStyle={styles.checkbox}/>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{members[item].first}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{members[item].last}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{item.Weight}</Text>
      </View>
```

I'm attempting to align the Checkbox in the center of that View. I originally tried it with out a view.  Here is my style:

```
  checkbox: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
  checkboxContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "25%",
    backgroundColor: "gray",
    alignItems:"center"
  }
```

The result is:
[image]

I have also tried:
checkbox: {
backgroundColor: "yellow",
alignSelf: "center",
},

How can I get that centered?

Comment: alignItems:"center" should be justifyContent: "center" ... justifyContent goes with the flexDirection, alignItems goes opposed to the flexDirection.

Comment: That's it, want to post as the answer? @JoeFitzsimmons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alignItems: "center"
```

should be:

```
justifyContent: "center"
```

justifyContent goes with the flexDirection, alignItems goes opposed to the flexDirection.